# Tikz picture position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to take this figure opposite to 1 , how can I do? Actually how can I change picture's  position as I want?

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
    \definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
    \textbf{1)}\newline
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-5.003269918455611,-3.3529348860915125) rectangle (10.415703512539228,5.13457342454785);
    \fill[line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq,fill=rvwvcq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (-1.16,2.85) -- (-3.82,-1.57) -- (3.56,-1.55) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-3.82,-1.57);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (3.56,-1.55);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55)-- (-1.16,2.85);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476) circle (2.5pt);
    \end{scriptsize}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image: I want to like that]

[image]
I want like that

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't quite understand your problem. What exactly do you want to do? Can you add a freehand drawing of the desired result?

Comment: Hi. I add freehand

Answer (score 5):

The real problem here is that the bounding box of your diagram is too large. Add

```
\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
```

right before `\end{tikzpicture}` to draw a frame along the bounding box, and you'll see this:

[image]

This is caused by the `\clip`, so remove that line, and you get this:

[image]

If you want it a little bit higher, as in your image, remove the `\newline` and add

```
baseline={([yshift=-\baselineskip]current bounding box.north)}
```

to the options of the `tikzpicture`. There is no need for the additional `\tikz`.

Finally though, are you making a list? If so, I'd recommend using a list environment, you can use the features of the `enumitem` package to customize the look of the list, as in this example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % added
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*)}]
\item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, baseline=(current bounding box.south), baseline={([yshift=-\baselineskip]current bounding box.north)}]
%  \clip(-5.003269918455611,-3.3529348860915125) rectangle (10.415703512539228,5.13457342454785); %% remove this line
\fill[line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq,fill=rvwvcq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (-1.16,2.85) -- (-3.82,-1.57) -- (3.56,-1.55) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-3.82,-1.57);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (3.56,-1.55);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55)-- (-1.16,2.85);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476) circle (2.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}

%\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west); % to indicate the bounding box of the diagram
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really explanatory information

Answer (score 3):

The clip operation widens the bounding box of the image, by removing it, it just frames the triangle.

The 1) is written before the image code, I position it with the `node` operation.

```
\node[below right] at (current bounding box.north west) {{1)}};
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
    \definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
%    \textbf{1)}\newline
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
%    \clip(-5.003269918455611,-3.3529348860915125) rectangle (10.415703512539228,5.13457342454785);
    \fill[line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq,fill=rvwvcq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (-1.16,2.85) -- (-3.82,-1.57) -- (3.56,-1.55) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-3.82,-1.57);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (3.56,-1.55);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55)-- (-1.16,2.85);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476) circle (2.5pt);
    \end{scriptsize}

    \node[below right] at (current bounding box.north west) {{1)}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in the code

```
\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-1.2cm]current bounding box.west)}]{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{document}
    \definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
    \definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
    \textbf{1)}\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-1.2cm]current bounding box.west)}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-5.003269918455611,-3.3529348860915125) rectangle (10.415703512539228,5.13457342454785);
    \fill[line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq,fill=rvwvcq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (-1.16,2.85) -- (-3.82,-1.57) -- (3.56,-1.55) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-3.82,-1.57);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (3.56,-1.55);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55)-- (-1.16,2.85);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{document}
```

**EDIT  - To cater for the change in handrawn sketch and comments of OP**

To use  `xshift` you need to use the `overlay` option -- add the following line in your code just after `\begin{tikzpicture}` options

```
remember picture, 
overlay, 
baseline={(current bounding box.base)}, 
yshift=-2cm, 
xshift=4cm,
```

The output--

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
    \definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
    \textbf{1)}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
                        overlay, 
                        baseline={(current bounding box.base)}, 
                        yshift=-2cm, 
                        xshift=4cm, 
                        scale=0.8, 
                        line cap=round,
                        line join=round,
                        >=triangle 45,
                        x=1.0cm,
                        y=1.0cm,]
    \clip(-5.003269918455611,-3.3529348860915125) rectangle (10.415703512539228,5.13457342454785);
    \fill[line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq,fill=rvwvcq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (-1.16,2.85) -- (-3.82,-1.57) -- (3.56,-1.55) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-3.82,-1.57);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (3.56,-1.55);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55)-- (-1.16,2.85);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-1.16,2.85)-- (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556);
    \draw [line width=2.pt,color=wrwrwr] (-3.82,-1.57)-- (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1.16,2.85) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.82,-1.57) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (3.56,-1.55) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-2.7200080786122416,-1.56701899208296) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-0.9600210043918271,-1.562249379415696) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.1000722668585952,-1.5566664708215214) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.4001169195517105,-1.5531433145811606) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (0.2994927758991701,1.4894558868736556) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (1.60355056870581,0.27380879188441476) circle (2.5pt);
    \end{scriptsize}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{document}
```

Though @TorbjørnT. has correctly brought out the `clip` factor, however when I ran the code I was not able to find any error-- you can experiment with and without the `clip` code to see what suits you

Comment: Thanks, so much. I also want to shift left. Can I use xshift how?

Comment: The problem with using `overlay` is that it makes the bounding box have "zero" size, meaning that TeX doesn't know the diagram takes up as much space as it does, when it lays out the page. As a result, any text you add after the diagram will be placed on top of it. (Just try adding some lorem ipsum text after `\end{tikzpicture}`.) Perhaps suggest using `\hspace` to move it left/right instead, while using `baseline` to move it up/down?